# How ELL can help improve the quality of questions. A few suggestions

Tags: feature-request

**EDIT**: I wish to revise my original proposals and re-present them to the community for consideration. If users agree on any of the points could they please add a comment. If they agree on ALL the points then a vote-up is sufficient. If they disagree on **two or more** points then please vote-down. In order to gage response as of today this post has -9;  August 13 2013.

1. Before a member can post a question or give an answer he or she must **tick/check a box saying they have understood what questions can or cannot be asked**. For example, which questions are considered general reference, which are off-topic or asking for writing advice and that they might find the answer by using the search tool on the website. These "tips" should be explained in the user's native tongue, a **multilingual FAQ** if you prefer.
2. A **Terms and conditions tick/check box** should avoid *some* abuse of the system, that is, people posting multiple questions on the same day and never answering back (for one thing) or posting the same question twice on different days or on EL&U and vice-versa. If someone has ticked the box it means they have read the terms, understood and agree with them.
3. The profile page should have a **visual reminder** that the user has forgotten to award an answer or has not posted *any comments* (read: given further clarifications, responded to users' requests for more context etc...) for over 3 questions or commented on any of the answers provided. Failure to do so *might* result in their *future* questions either being deleted or being put on hold. (All this in T&C)
4. **A limit to the number of questions a user can post in one day** (or lets say two hours). The OP should realize that his/her posting anything between 5 or 10 questions a day is counter-productive. The OP should be advised to wait until his first question has at least received one answer before moving onto the next. Posting several questions on the same day can *look* akin to spamming, especially if the questions are posted within minutes of each other.
5. I really believe that the site needs a **multilingual FAQ page**, even without the tick box, it would make everything so much easier.

---

June 2013

**EDIT:**
I understand and accept that my suggestions are not shared by the community.

**2nd EDIT:** May I point out that I did say: `Failure to do so "might" result` etc. Perhaps I am being pedantic. Moreover, I realize that my suggestion of deleting questions is unpopular for the excellent reasons given by Kiamlaluno, but it has been taken in the wrong spirit, and I should have made myself clearer. However, I am pleased to hear that a multilingual FAQs is under "process".

Answer (score 6):

Just asking questions is not forbidden, in the same way just answering question is not forbidden. If by *answering back* you mean commenting on the given answer, that is considered not constructive, when the comment is simply "Thank you." "+1 Thank you." "+1 Great answer." or similar comment. The [purpose of comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) is:

- Request clarification from the author
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post
- Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated)

The same page says when comments should not used:

- Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post
- Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer
- Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!")
- Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!")
- Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point
- Discussion of community behavior or site policies

If by "the user has forgotten or has never replied to more than 5 questions/answers" you are referring to the users accepting answers for the questions they ask, there was an indicator that showed the percentage of accepted answers for the user who asked the question, but that has been removed because caused not constructive comments. They could have made it visible only to the OP, in the question page, or in the profile page, but they decided not to do so.
If by that you mean commenting back to the users who answers questions, that is not obligatory. Deleting a question just because a user "has never replied to more than 5 questions/answers" is excessive; it is also wrong for the following reasons:

- The question could be useful to future users; the OP not having replied to more than 5 answers/questions doesn't make the question less useful for future users, nor does it make the given answers less useful.
- If the question is on-topic, constructive, and a real question, deleting the question for that reason is against the rights of who answered. That is the same reason why the users who asked a question are not able to delete them if there are up-voted answers.
- If questions were deleted for that reason, there would be less users who answer to questions and the reason is easy to understand: Why would users take their time to answer to questions that apparently don't have any problem, when they can be deleted if the OP has never replied to more than 5 questions/answers?

I think the multilingual support is planned. The first step seems to be the support of international characters in tags, which is the reason why proposals like [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) are on hold. I am not sure if a multilingual Help Center is going to be implemented, implemented only in those sites where a language different from English is allowed, or implemented in all the Stack Exchange sites, including the ones where English is required to answer or ask questions, such as [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: kiam, I never understood what "to be the support of international characters in tags" precisely means. What is the problem to support IC in tags? Is there something to be added to the software?

Comment: Probably you cannot use letters used in languages different from English. I guess that non even accented letters can be used for tags, as also [a proposal in Portuguese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) is on hold.

Comment: kiam, if so we will have the same problem with IL&U, I guess. In fact we have a lot of accented words, do you think something?

Comment: Any updates on the multilingual FAQs?

Comment: *I think the multilingual support is planned.* Multilingual FAQ anyone? Anyone?